# Overriding Constructor Arguments

Tags: java, constructor

How can I get the value of a variable without overwriting that variable with constructor arguments?

For example:

```
public class Example {

String something = "";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

  public Example()
  {

  }

  public Example(String something){
    this.something = something;
  }

  // Getter method
  public String getSomething() {
    return something;
  }

   public void changeValues() {
   System.out.println("Please change the string!");
   something = sc.next();
   Example set = new Example(something);
   }   
}//example


public class AnotherClass {
    Example test = new Example() 
    // I don't want to overwrite this so I set this to null
    String something2 = test.getSomething(); 
    // the above puts in a null reference instead of the text
  }
```

Please keep in mind that I don't want to hard code anything in AnotherClass for the constructor argument and the changeValues method has to stay in the Example class.

**Edit**: I instantiated the something variable with a space, I then prompted the user which should have stored that in the variable then passed it off to the constructor. Now, I get back the original instantiating space instead of the input!

Comment: You seem to be confused. Each `Example` instance gets its own, separate copy of `something`. There is no "overwriting" here.

Comment: If each one get's it's own copy of something, that copy should still be the foo variable that got prompted for though, correct?

Comment: No. Not correct. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: Oh, so the other class had its own instance of something which was already set to null by the default constructor of the class! Really helpful. I didn't think of that. Thanks.

Comment: @Brian I strongly suggest you to get hold of basic OOP concepts first.

Comment: I knew static variables had only one copy per object which essentially makes them global. I guess a combination of little practice/forgetting material contributes to a loss of concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make much sense.

- If you are talking about "overriding", constructors are not overridden because they are not inherited.
- If you are talking about the constructor for `Example` "overwriting" the `something` variable, then simply supply a default constructor.  But that is not going to change anything, because when you don't explicitly initialize `something` it will be default initialized to `null` anyway.  In fact, the existing constructor isn't clobbering anything when you call it with a `null` argument.

---

Then we have your strange `changeValues()` method:

```
public void changeValues() {
    System.out.println("Please change the string! ")
    String foo = sc.next();
    Example set = new Example(foo);
}
```

What this *actually* does is to:

1. prompt the user
2. read a string
3. create a new Example instance, and then
4. throws it away!!

What you probably should be doing is this:

```
    something = sc.next();
```

Comment: Even when I do change the instance variable to capture the input from the prompt and then spit that back out to the constructor I get null returned.